# How do I do the equivalent of "git repack -ad" with jgit?

Tags: jgit

I have implemented a `DfsRepository` using jgit-2.0.0.201206130900. It works great but I want to repack it so that I only have one packfile. How do I do that via jgit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working. `DfsGarbageCollector` basically does the equivalent of `repack -d`. To get the `repack -a` behavior, use `DfsPackCompactor`:

```
void repack(DfsRepository repo) throws IOException {
    DfsGarbageCollector gc = new DfsGarbageCollector(repo);
    gc.pack(null);

    // update the list of packs for getPacks() below
    // otherwise not all packs are compacted
    repo.scanForRepoChanges();

    // only compact if there are multiple pack files
    DfsPackFile[] packs = repo.getObjectDatabase().getPacks();

    if (packs.length > 1) {
        DfsPackCompactor compactor = new DfsPackCompactor(repo);

        for (DfsPackFile pack : packs) {
            compactor.add(pack);
        }

        compactor.compact(null);
    }
}
```

That's not quite all though.

`DfsGarbageCollector` creates a separate packfile for the garbage.

The easiest way I found to "delete" the garbage packfile was to return a `DfsOutputStream` from my `DfsObjDatabase.writePackFile()` implementation that simply threw away the data if the pack file's source was `PackSource.UNREACHABLE_GARBAGE`.